# Firefox 15 border-image failing

Tags: firefox, css

The CSS3 `border-image` property has stopped working in firefox 15 using the syntax that worked in firefox 14,
http://jsfiddle.net/uzZVf/2/

Of course the prefix has been removed, but even without it, it fails.

Are there new syntax requirements that didn't exist before? How can I get `border-image` functioning correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add: `border-image-width: 4px 4px 4px 4px;` to your CSS, otherwise Firefox sets it to 1px wide even with your other border CSS.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/uzZVf/4/

The Mozilla dev team updated the border-image specs from the [2008 Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-css3-background-20080910/#the-border-image) to the [2011 Candidate Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/CR-css3-background-20110215/#border-images), please see [this article](http://dbaron.org/log/20120612-border-image) for details.

Comment: You need to add: `border-image-width: 4px 4px 4px 4px;`, otherwise Firefox sets it to 1px wide even with your current CSS.

Comment: The fix was to add `fill` and set the `border-style` to `solid`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your style now needs to be like this (XYZ = border width):

```
        border-width: XYZpx;

        border-image-width: XYZpx XYZpx XYZpx XYZpx;
        border-image-slice: fill;
        border-style: solid;
```